# ksoap passing a long value from an int

Tags: java, casting, int, long-integer, ksoap

I'm trying to send some info to s webService. It requires a long value that I have to get from a EditText field:

If I do:

```
long nit; // on the Client class    
client.nit = 34546365755;
```

It works! But, if i get the value from the editText and convert it into an int, it does not. I've tried:

```
int cc = Integer.valueOf("xxx");
client.nit = Long.parseLong(cc);
```

and

```
Integer cc = Integer.valueOf("xx");
client.nit = cc.longValue();
```

I also found this method in an answer

```
public static long castToLong(Object o) {
    Number n = (Number) o;
    return n.longValue();
}
```

But it's still not working, unless I type some fake values. I'm lost, help!

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to convert an integer value to a long value using a wrong method.
   `Long.parseLong(str);`
This method requires string value.
Try this: 
    `Long.parseLong(string_value_of_edittext);`